# Data/analyses on distribution on academic research income across research active staff

Tags: funding, reference-request, salary

Does anyone know of any analyses of the level of ‘research income inequality’ in research grant income across research active staff? Ideally by field, country, and time?
I.e if you had a list of all research active staff, and the research grant income associated with them in a given year as PI or Co-I, and arranged the list from lowest to highest, what would the distribution look like, and what would the gini coefficient and other measures of inequality (eg 10:90 ratio) be?
I would expect something like an outsized hockey stick, but also that there would be greater inequality in less well funded fields and vice versa.

Comment: That's a fairly broad request. It might be easier to find numbers from specific funding agencies. [NIH noted that 10% of the investigators receive over 40% of NIH funding](https://www.nih.gov/about-nih/who-we-are/nih-director/statements/new-nih-approach-grant-funding-aimed-optimizing-stewardship-taxpayer-dollars). Whether that's an efficient use of money or not [is a matter of debate](http://www.sciencemag.org/news/2017/06/critics-challenge-nih-finding-bigger-labs-aren-t-necessarily-better).